# How can I detect links which point to domain squatters?

Tags: domains, links

I know how to find dead links which go to 404 pages. However, these days, not many links actually go dead, but instead they end up going to a domain squatter.

Is there any way to find out whether a website is actually a domain squatter without actually going to each site with my browser and examining it to see if there is a picture of a girl with a rucksack or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Possible detection methods for parked pages/domains:

#### Find junk phrases

Do a case insensitive search for common generic junk phrases such as, "what you need, when you need it" and "your source for virtually anything!".

#### Find invitations to purchase

Look for text such as "inquire about this domain" and "this domain may be for sale".

#### Test for 404s on random subpages

Visit `testdomain.example/randomstring`. If you get a 404, or the page itself contains the text '404' or 'not found', it's probably not parked.

#### Test for redirects on random subpages

Other parked domain systems redirect `testdomain.example/randomstring` to `testdomain.example`.

#### Search for the domain name in meta tags

Several parked domain templates use the following format for the author meta tag:

`<meta name="author" content="Nameofdomain.example" />`

Others put it in the description:

`<meta name="description" content="nameofdomain.example">`

In each case, the domain is the *only* thing in the 'content' attribute. This is unlikely to be the case for active sites.

#### Look for the frameset tag

Some parked domain templates use the `<frameset>` tag with multiple internal frames to pull in external content (often from information.com), but otherwise feature nothing else on the page.

#### Use multiple tests

No single one of these tests are necessarily reliable indicators of a parked domain on their own. You will likely have to combine multiple tests to create your own algorithm, then test and refine it based on a suite of known parked domains and known active ones.

Comment: Be good if there was some code implementing this! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are things you can look for. Is the dominant element on the page an iFrame? Is the response a `301`/`302` that takes you off-domain? (many squatters will simply `302` or `301` you to their landing page). Is the link/text ratio incredibly high?

I'd say it's very difficult, but that's at least some common characteristics.

There also seems to be a project on the Wikipedia `linkrot` page referring to some project that attempts to do this: [Wikipedia talk:Link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Link_rot) - details are sketchy though.

Comment: Your edit has made my answer invalid, but I'll leave it for prosperities sake.

Comment: I don't think it has, but I've edited the question to try to clarify.